# Offline Installation and Updating of Microsoft 365 on Remote Desktop Services (RDS) Server

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft

In an environment where my RDS 2019 server lacks internet connectivity, what steps should I follow to download Microsoft 365 installation files to another machine, transfer them to the server, and then proceed with an offline installation?

Furthermore, once Microsoft 365 is installed, how can I ensure that it remains up to date with the latest features and security patches without an online connection?

I am looking for a comprehensive method that allows the periodic transfer and application of updates from an external source to my RDS setup.

We have attempted to use Office 2019 Home and Business on an RDS server, but it's incompatible. Is there an alternative Office product that supports RDS servers, other than Office 365?